# how do i combine post meta data and taxonomy in a WP_query $args array Worpresss

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how to get the following code to work as one wp_query . i'm trying to filter the loop on the meta values and the taxonomy values:

Both of these sections work independently but i'm looking to tie these into one query..?

I have tried various combinations but am getting no where....any ideas of the best approach to this issue...?

```
  $args = array(
    array(
   'post_type' => 'job_listing',
  'meta_key' => 'geo_short_address',
  'meta_value' => $area


   ),

'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'job_type',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => $jobtype
    ),
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'job_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $jobcat
    )
)
   );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if your argument array is one level too deep. Try this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'job_listing',
    'meta_key' => 'geo_short_address',
    'meta_value' => $area,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'job_type',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $jobtype
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'job_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $jobcat
        )
    )
);
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'job_listing',
    'meta_key' => 'geo_short_address',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
           'key' => 'geo_short_address',
           'value' => $area
        )
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'job_type',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $jobtype
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'job_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $jobcat
        )
    )
);
```